# Itext building a XML Tree from PDF

Tags: algorithm, itext

How can we build a XML Tree Like we have in example http://demo.itextsupport.com/xfademo/

I am thinking on following lines:

```
    `AcroFields form = pdfReader.AcroFields;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> de in form.Fields)
    {trace(de.Key.ToString());}`
```

It gives me string like - 
topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Header[0].EntityArea[0].f1_01_0_[0]

I am thinking of using this information to build XML Tree using Graph Traverse algorithm.
Is there any other information from API that can be used to accomplish this task?

Comment: Before anyone can answer this question, you need to tell us: is there an XFA stream available inside the PDF? Look for the `isXfaPresent()` method in http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=164

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for your reply, the form I am parsing is http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf - this does not have XFA stream. I am building application which is going to fill various tax forms, some will be XFA and some will be acro. First step of my application will be to put a XML representation of pdf in database. For XFA it will be xfa:data element, but for acro there is no such direct way.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you to read the XFDF spec and to create your XML according to that spec. iText doesn't provide any code to do this, but by following the XFDF spec, your solution is more future-proof. For instance: iText can merge an AcroForm with an XFDF file.